# Is there a difference in how Java 8 and Java 7 handle NumberFormatException?

Tags: java

I'm attempting to solve one of CodeEval's [challenges](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/82/). Everytime I submit an answer, which works perfectly fine with Java 8(1.8.0_11) on my local system, I am thrown this exception. CodeEval uses Java 7.

Code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class ArmStrong
{
    public static boolean howstrong(int str, int[] ong)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ong.length; i++)
        {
            count += Math.pow(ong[i], ong.length);
        }
        return (count == str);
    }
    public static void bin(BufferedReader in)
        throws IOException, NumberFormatException
    {
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null && line.length() != 0)
        {
            int str = Integer.parseInt(line.trim());
            String[] lne = line.split("");
            int[] ong = new int[lne.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < lne.length; i++)
            {
                ong[i] = Integer.parseInt(lne[i]);
            }
            System.out.println(howstrong(str, ong));
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        FileReader inc = new FileReader(args[0]);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(inc);
        bin(in);
    }
}
```

My test file:

```
8538
153
9657
2446
407
6821
9474
4192
371
8208
7959
191
3348
370
1634
9192
5172
7543
6078
2908
```

Saving my test file with an extra newline char works fine as well.

Here is text from website:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at     java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
at Main.bin(Main.java:25)
at Main.main(Main.java:35)
```

Here is terminal output from my side:

```
false
true
false
false
true
false
true
false
true
true
false
false
false
true
true
false
false
false
false
false
```

Comment: why you throw your exceptions in main method? why do not you use try catch block?

Comment: Edited out NumberFormatException in main method. Other exceptions need to be declared. Try/catch was giving me the same problem as this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you'll find it's much simpler to implement with a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and [`nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) then using a `BufferedReader`. But first, your armstrong check seems to be incorrect (and I found it easier to simplify it). So let's start there with,

```
public static boolean isArmstrong(int val) {
    char[] chars = String.valueOf(val).toCharArray();
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        int digit = chars[i] - '0';
        count += Math.pow(digit, chars.length);
    }
    return (count == val);
}
```

Then we can use the `Scanner` in `main()` and test the numbers like,

```
Scanner scanner = null;
try {
    File f = new File("/home/efrisch/test.txt");
    scanner = new Scanner(f);
    while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println(isArmstrong(scanner.nextInt()) ? "True"
                : "False");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (scanner != null) {
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```